# multiple inputs - Problems with array

Tags: php, html, mysqli

it is such that I need to use multiple inputs on my side,

I've tried to do like this but it does not work as it will not show up on the page at all in some manner.

**HTML**

```
<div id="onlinetestside">
<div id="onlinetestsidealt"><?php echo $ordet;?></div>
<input type="text" name="ord[]" maxlength="190">
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
//ordetalt its coming from database.
$alt = $_POST["ord"];
if($ordetalt == $alt)
{
    echo $ordetalt . " og " . $alt; 
}
else
{
    echo "Error " . $ordetalt . " and " . $alt;
}
```

**error appears like this:**

*Error Hej and Array*

What I want to get to it shall be such that **"$ordetalt == $alt"** have the same content and it fits together.

**EIDT**

Here I show the entire code where I need to download some code to the side.

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT id, ordet, ordetalt FROM test WHERE getid = ?')) { 
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$id = $_GET['id'];
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $ordet, $ordetalt);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
?>
<div id="onlinetestside">
    <div id="onlinetestsidealt"><?php echo $ordet;?></div>
    <input type="text" name="ord[]" maxlength="190">
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<?php
    //ordetalt its coming from database
    $alt = $_POST["ord"];
    if($ordetalt == $alt)
    {
        echo $ordetalt . " og " . $alt; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error " . $ordetalt . " and " . $alt;
    }
}
$stmt->close();
```

}

EIDT EIDT

```
$i = 0;
    $a = $i++;
    $alt = $_POST["ord"][$a];
    if($ordetalt == $alt)
    {
        echo $ordetalt . " og " . $alt; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error " . $ordetalt . " and " . $alt;
    }
```

Comment: `$_POST["ord"]` is an array, so `$alt` is an array. What is `$ordetalt`?

Comment: @Barmar `$ _POST["ord"]` is the same as `$alt`, but `$ordetalt` of it comes out of the database

Comment: And what is in it? Is it an array or a string? If it's a string, why are you trying to compare it with an array? And what do you expect to happen when you echo an array?

Answer (score 0):

Barmar is spot on, your line

```
$alt = $_POST["ord"];
```

Should read

```
$alt = $_POST["ord"][0];
```

OR

change your html like so:

```
<div id="onlinetestside">
<div id="onlinetestsidealt"><?php echo $ordet;?></div>
<input type="text" name="ord" maxlength="190">
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is close to reading problem but this is how right now it looks like this right now. see here [link](http://billedeupload.dk/?v=O5iJ0.png)

Comment: It's all in the html.

See : <input type="text" name="ord[]" maxlength="190">,

the ord[] automatically creates an array.

If you don't want the array, just use ord, not ord[]

Comment: Updated question, I'm afraid that's about as far as i can help.

Comment: it does not work, now remove the last input field and takes only a letter,

Comment: You should change only HTML    OR only PHP.

If you only change both, that's exactly what happens.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know any other way to explain it.